# IE on VirtualBox to visit http://localhost on Mac OS X host

Tags: mac-osx, virtualbox, localhost

I use VirtualBox on my Mac to run IE for testing, but sometimes I want to test http://localhost. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Localhost on the Mac, or localhost on the VirtualBox VM?  From the Mac, or from the VirtualBox VM?

Comment: keep in mind that every machine thinks that **it** is named "localhost".

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal, and type "ifconfig" to find out the IP address of the Mac OS X network interface.  Look for en0: or en1:, for the field named "inet".  It should be something like 192.168.1.100.  Then type that in IE's address bar, like `http://192.168.1.100/`

(By the way, I don't have enough rep to do it, but this should probably be on SuperUser)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like putty to forward a port from within the VM to localhost on the Mac OS.